# Clojure - idiomatic way to handle database persistence

Tags: orm, clojure, persistence, idioms

I am an experienced Java and SQL developer considering Clojure for my next project. I have spent some time studying the basics but still struggling to understand the idiomatic way to painlessly handle interactions with a relational database **with regards to updates**.

Most of the threads I have read focus on the query side which for me is actually not a problem since I am very comfortable with SQL and consider jdbc.next to be more than adequate for my querying needs (maybe augmented by Toucan 'hydration' support if required).

My main concern is how to handle **persistence** e.g. how to automatically persist a modified (nested) map(?) back to the database without the need to keep track of state myself.

As a side note, I have enough experience with both Hibernate itself and JPA and still feel they are too rigid and verbose.

The tool I consider ideal on this regard is https://www.sqlalchemy.org/ which I have previously used via jython with a great sense of satisfaction.

Thanks a lot for all your input.

***Update based on some comments/questions below:***

To - hopefully - set the context more clearly, suppose a web application shopping cart scenario: A new customer checks out. An insert needs to be performed for the customer, possibly another for the shipping address, another for the order and these need to be synchronized in a way that referential integrity is preserved. Doing all the steps manually is of course an option but the more involved the scenario the more complex handling becomes. My database is relational.

**Second update**

To clear up my question further, my problem is not how to issue the 'insert/update/delete' statements but more of keeping track of which statements must be issued according to the current state of things.

I would expect the 'ORM' layer to track which of my 'data' are new, which have been modified, deleted etc. and execute the above snippet automatically in a consistent way similar to Hibernate's entity manager (please have a look at the below link https://www.sitepoint.com/hibernate-introduction-persisting-java-objects/ in section "Performing CRUD Operations on Entities" for an example of the intended functionality).

Alternatively I would like to be able to identify what happened on each 'piece' of my data (object graph in hibernate parlance) and then execute the snippet you shared by traversing each element, 'querying' its state/status and inferring the correct statement to send back to the database.

From my understanding of the language so far this functionality is native(?) to clojure data structures - but I have not been able to put my finger on it yet.

Comment: I might not be understanding your problem well, but I think the Clojure way would be to avoid state if at all possible. Query your dB when needed, transform the data, display result. Similarly a transaction back into the dB will not change the state of your application.

Comment: what is your question then? if you want to perform an update, just execute it with jdbc. if you want to keep a track of "state" (or "changes"), you might want to take look at https://www.datomic.com/

Comment: To - hopefully - set the context more clearly, suppose a web application shopping cart scenario: A new customer checks out. An insert needs to be performed for the customer, another for the order and these need to be synchronized in a way that referential integrity is preserved. Doing all the steps manually is of course an option but the more involved the scenario the more complex handling becomes. My database is relational.

Comment: Turing complete programming languages are differentiated by what they make easy vs what they don't. Complex state persistence (as a.k. pointed out) is what datomic is for (and it can sit on top of relational DBs just fine), but based on your description of what you want I'm wondering if you don't really grok what Clojure is about. "Update" isn't really something Clojure strives to make easy. If you don't buy in to the underlying concepts and think of it as a nicer way to write Java I think you're going to encounter a lot of friction...

Answer (score 1):

You say you're using `next.jdbc` -- the documentation has examples of performing updates and inserts, using transactions, to ensure consistency, so I'm not sure what you're really asking here.

The `next.jdbc.sql` namespace contains `update!` and `insert!` functions. The `next.jdbc` namespace has `with-transaction` for creating transactions around multiple operations.

`update!` returns the count of rows updated. `insert!` returns the newly-inserted keys (as best it can, based on how the specific database driver you use works).

It's common in Clojure programs that deal with the database to try to separate out the persistence code from the pure business logic so you'd typically have something like:

```
(defn some-process [...]
  (let [data    (some-database-query ...)
        updates (perform-business-logic ...)]
    (with-transaction [tx ...]
      ...based on what is in updates...
      (update-something tx ...)
      (insert-something tx ...)
      (insert-more-stuff tx ...))))
```

If subsequent inserts/updates rely on generated keys from earlier inserts, you'd use a `let` to capture the result of the earlier inserts, so you could access those keys in the other inserts/updates.

It would be reasonable to refactor the above so the whole `with-transaction` form was in a separate function that `some-process` called, passing in the `updates` and the connection/datasource.

If that doesn't answer your question, can you try to clarify what you are really asking?

Also, feel free to join the Clojurians Slack and post questions in the `#sql` channel if you want an interactive conversation with other Clojurians about relational database persistence.

Clojure Slack: https://clojurians.slack.com

Self-signup via: http://clojurians.net (or I can post a custom invite link here if you have problems with self-signup)

Comment: Hello,

thank you for the detailed answer and the links. I already signed up to closurians.net and updated my question based on your input. Any further comment would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

An ORM does not make super great sense, either anymore or in Clojure.  A new, improved technique is CQRS, which can be applied without special tools and works out very well in Clojure.  See Martin Fowler’s essay about Command/Query Responsibility Segregation at https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found something that suits my use case. I can use datascript as my local data store then once ready I can(?) extract all changes and push them back to my 'master' database.

It seems people have tried to do it, as described in [this](https://groups.google.com/g/clojure/c/Og5rU49rMvM) thread:

> datomic <-> datascript transfers  I am knocking out a webapp, backed
> by datomic on the server side and planning to use datascript in the
> client.
>
> the plan is to:
>
> 1. export a bunch of related data to the client (datomic
>    query/pull/entity apis to create edn data suitable for transact into
>    datascript)    -- could be a one-time thing or seed data with more
>    getting pulled later.
> 2. let the user change it about (transactions
>    into datascript)
> 3. save all user changes back to datomic (could send
>    complete list of transactions made on client back to server, but
>    ideally one tx representing sum of all changes)
>
> One issue to deal with is identity. For example upserts and
> retractions (on both client and server) need to happen to the right
> entities.
>
> I have some plans for how it will all work, but before going into details I am just > curious if anyone else has considered this general approach?

There is also a [link](https://gist.github.com/henryw-erudine/73cbcdea1eda150e78da) to a code file (which I will have to digest).

Thanks a lot for all comments and the answer!